# Using Named Ranges for Data Validation

Tags: c#, closedxml

Is it possible to use a named range for data validation using ClosedXML?

Something like the following:

```
worksheet.cell(2,2).SetDataValidation().List(worksheet.NamedRanges.NamedRange("DataValidation").Ranges)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
worksheet.cell(2,2).SetDataValidation().List(Main.Range("DataValidation"));
```